# URL to list with view passed on as GUID

Tags: list-view, guid

Is there a possibility to create a URL to a list/library with a certain view but not using on the .aspx in the URL but the GUID of that view?

So not:

```
 https://company.com/sites/DocLib/Forms/View1.aspx
```

but something like:

```
https://company.com/sites/DocLib/Forms/whatwever.aspx?View={16E9F3B1-7950-4A3C-A18A-8E6FBE91B9A8}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add this custom js code to the page.
It gets the ViewID and listName from the URL, fetches all the view for that list and redirect to the page the with given Guid.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
function getParameterByName(name) {
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
    var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
        results = regex.exec(location.search);
    return results === null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}


var viewID = getParameterByName("ViewId");
var listName = getParameterByName("ListName");
//var viewID="2c45ea14-acza-4b4e-8855e-3b751b354a5c";
//var listName="TestList;

var requestUri = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/" +
        "getByTitle('"+listName+"')/Views";
var requestHeaders = { "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose" };
$.ajax({
    url: requestUri,
    async: false,
    contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
    headers: requestHeaders,
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);

        $(data.d.results).each(function (index) {
            console.log(data.d.results[index].Id)
            if (data.d.results[index].Id==viewID){
                var newUrl=data.d.results[index].ServerRelativeUrl;
                if (!(window.location.indexOf(newUrl)>-1)){
                    window.location=newUrl;
                }
            }
        });
    },
    error: function (msg) {
        console.log(msg.responseText);
    }
});

</script>
```